# Are sysbench results comparable between versions and distros?

Tags: benchmark

I have a machine which i can boot into either Ubuntu 18.04.5 or Fedora 32. I have had some performance issues, so i thought i would run a quick benchmark on both distros. I installed sysbench from the package manager and ran the CPU and memory benchmarks, for which i noted the events per second and total operations per second respectively. The machine has four physical cores, so i ran with 1 and 4 threads.

Ubuntu has sysbench 1.0.11 (using system LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3).

Fedora has sysbench 1.0.17 (using system LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3).

The version and the results are the only difference in the output on the two distros; the options like number of primes, block size, etc, are the same.

The results are:

```
Distro          CPU (1 thr)  CPU (4 thr)  memory (1 thr)  memory (4 thr)
Ubuntu 18.04.5      1213.05      4384.59      5332997.51      8069089.73
Fedora 32         156442.30    564670.95      6220026.17      9055910.28
```

The differences in the memory results seem plausible, but the differences in the CPU results are rather surprising.

Should i expect these to be more similar?

Answer (score 1):

Points of interest:

- Packages versions are different enough, the new version might contain optimizations not found in the old one
- Most Linux distros compile packages differently, i.e. not only using different compilers but different compiler optimizations/flags - they might affect your scores as well.
- Most likely you can run Ubuntu's sysbench in Fedora directly without any issues - please do and check the results. If they mirror your Ubuntu results that will confirm either or both of the previous points.